# Check java version programmatically on IBM i using CL or RPGLE

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I have a situation where I have to check the java version on IBM i is equal to 1.8.

In my CL program there is a call of RUNJVA which runs a jar file which is dependent on java 1.8. I want to run that command only if IBM i machine has Java 1.8.

There are many ways on IBM i to see java version but to check version programmatically I need  version information in a variable somehow.

One approach is to run command

RUNJVA CLASS(*VERSION) OUTPUT(*PRINT)

and read version from spool file. However this approach should work but I am looking for more seamless approach. Also reading spool file for information doesn't seems to be a good approach

Comment: try ```System.getProperty("java.version");```

Comment: @BorisChistov This is something what we can do in java. I have to check that in CL and then run java.

Comment: Why must you check first?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  If jdk80 is not present on system then I don't want to run this jar and want to execute some other code.

Comment: Note that you can have your main class compiled for Java 1.2 which should run on any JVM available on the i even though the rest of the jar is for Java 8.  Then your java class can explicity try to invoke Java 8 code and fail gracefully if the JVM is not compatible.   Any heuristic looking at strings may fail at a later time (as has happened with Oracle JVM)

Comment: I may have over thought my answer below. What happens in your CL if you do execute the jar against the incorrect JDK version? Is there a message you could monitor for with MONMSG in the CL?

Comment: Did you have a chance to run the below? Or give the JDK run on the incompatible version to see if a useful message is thrown that you can monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is considered elegant or not, but you won't have to deal with a spool file at least. I wrote the output of java -version to a data area which you could then pick up:

Create a data area to hold the value of the first row of the java_version file. You could add these into your CL:

`QSH CMD('java -version 2> /some/IFSdir/java_version')`

`QSH CMD('head -n 1 /some/IFSdir/java_version | datarea -w /qsys.lib/doug
.lib/testing.dtaara')`

Then just grab the data area into a variable and evaluate there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Use RUNRMTCMD to execute 'java -version'. Capture output or error, parse and find out the version.

Comment: I don't want to run command remotely. I want to check it for same system where my application is running. Can you please explain more.